# Optimizing an objective function with inevitable division by zero error

Tags: algorithm, optimization, heuristics, divide-by-zero

**Update - June 6th - Start**

Sorry, I couldn't spare the time to abstract the code, but the problem is solved by doing some more googling and applying one of the easiest general solution. That is, to add min value(some value close to zero) to the suspicious denominators

**Update - June 6th - End**

I'm trying to solve a very complicated optimization problem with meta heuristic algorithms. Because, it's very complicated it's hard to modify the problem definition to avoid division by zero.

Existing library codes seem to be able to deal with division by zero error somehow.

But my own implementation of some searching algorithm is halting from division by zero error.

The first solution comes to my mind is just ignore/skip the solution causing division by zero error. That is, the solution is not giving any feedback/effect on following search. But this approach seems to be kind of method specific. I hope there is some one-time patch approach can pre-process the problem so that any searching algorithm solving it doesn't suffer from the division by zero error.

I want to know what's the custom/usual/general way to deal with division by zero when searching in solution space.

Below is the code

It's coded in google colab, so it's not well structured.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Opt_AI_Term_Project.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WtaxJeLu4jE_TOOqtftggqhUAsf8DQRB

# Implementation of Objective Function

## Implementation(Definitions Only)
"""

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Constants
e = np.e

# Parameters - [Unverified]
a_1 = 30
a_2 = 100
b_1 = 5.0
b_2 = np.log(2)/8
D_0 = 50
beta_1 = 0.5
beta_2 = 0.5
beta_3 = 0.5
c = 20.0
K = 500.0

# Parameters - [Verified]
alpha_1 = 1.0
alpha_2 = 1.0
alpha_3 = 1.0
gamma_1 = 0.4
gamma_2 = 0.4
gamma_3 = 0.3
delta_1 = 0.25
delta_2 = 0.3
delta_3 = 0.3
mu_1 = 4.0
mu_2 = 8.0
theta_0 = 0.2
theta_1 = 0.4
xi = 0.05
theta = lambda u: theta_0 + (theta_1 - theta_0)*e**(-xi*u)
S_0 = 50.0
h = 0.5
c_d = 5.0

# Control variables - [Verified]
def lambda_1(t, static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    if t>=0 and t<mu_1:
        first_term = gamma_1*(p_1 + (h + theta(u)*c_d)/theta(u))*((1 - e**(-delta_1*(mu_1 - t)))/delta_1)
        second_term = gamma_1*(h + theta(u)*c_d)*e**(theta(u)*t)/(theta(u)*(theta(u) - delta_1))*(1 - e**((theta(u) - delta_1)*(mu_1 - t)))
        third_term = lambda_1(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(-delta_1*(mu_1 - t))
    elif t>=mu_1 and t<mu_2:
        first_term = gamma_2*(p_2 + (h + theta(u)*c_d)/theta(u))*((1 - e**(-delta_2*(mu_2 - t)))/delta_2)
        second_term = gamma_2*(h + theta(u)*c_d)*e**(theta(u)*t)/(theta(u)*(theta(u) - delta_2))*(1 - e**((theta(u) - delta_2)*(mu_2 - t)))
        third_term = lambda_1(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(-delta_2*(mu_2 - t))
    elif t>=mu_2: # and t<T: simplified for numerical stability
        first_term = gamma_3*(p_3 + (h + theta(u)*c_d)/theta(u))*((1 - e**(-delta_3*(T - t)))/delta_3)
        second_term = gamma_3*(h + theta(u)*c_d)*e**(theta(u)*t)/(theta(u)*(theta(u) - delta_3))*(1 - e**((theta(u) - delta_3)*(T - t)))
        third_term = 0
    return first_term + second_term + third_term

def s_1(t, static_variables):
    return lambda_1(t, static_variables)/(2*alpha_1)

def s_2(t, static_variables):
    return lambda_1(t, static_variables)/(2*alpha_2)

def s_3(t, static_variables):
    return lambda_1(t, static_variables)/(2*alpha_3)

# Omegas - [Verified]
omega_1 = lambda u: (h + theta(u)*c_d)/theta(u)
omega_2 = lambda t: (e**(delta_1*t) - e**(-delta_1*t))/(2*delta_1)
omega_9 = lambda t: (e**(delta_2*t) - e**(2*delta_2*mu_1 - delta_2*t))/(2*delta_2)
omega_10 = lambda t: (e**(delta_3*t) - e**(2*delta_3*mu_2 - delta_3*t))/(2*delta_3)

# Omegas - [Unverified]
omega_3 = lambda t, u: (e**(-delta_1*t) - e**(-theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) - delta_1)
omega_4 = lambda t, u: (e**(delta_1*t) - e**(-theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) + delta_1)
omega_5 = lambda t, u: (e**(-delta_2*t) - e**((theta(u) - delta_2)*mu_1 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) - delta_2)
omega_6 = lambda t, u: (e**(delta_2*t) - e**((theta(u) + delta_2)*mu_1 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) + delta_2)
omega_7 = lambda t, u: (e**(-delta_3*t) - e**((theta(u) - delta_3)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) - delta_3)
omega_8 = lambda t, u: (e**(delta_3*t) - e**((theta(u) + delta_3)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) + delta_3)
omega_11 = lambda t, u: omega_4(t, u) - omega_3(t, u)
omega_12 = lambda t, u: omega_6(t, u) - e**(2*delta_2*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u)
omega_13 = lambda t, u: omega_8(t, u) - e**(2*delta_3*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u)

# State variables - [Verified]
def S(t, static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    if t>=0 and t<=mu_1:
        first_term = gamma_1*(p_1 + omega_1(u))*((1 - e**(-delta_1*t))/delta_1 - e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_2(t))/(2*alpha_1*delta_1)
        second_term = gamma_1*omega_1(u)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(-delta_1*t))/(theta(u) + delta_1) - e**((theta(u) - delta_1)*mu_1)*omega_2(t))/(2*alpha_1*(theta(u) - delta_1))
        third_term = lambda_1(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_2(t)/(2*alpha_1)
        fourth_term = S_0*e**(-delta_1*t)
    elif t>mu_1 and t<=mu_2:
        first_term = gamma_2*(p_2 + omega_1(u))*((1 - e**(delta_2*(mu_1 - t)))/delta_2 - e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_9(t))/(2*alpha_2*delta_2)
        second_term = gamma_2*omega_1(u)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**((theta(u) + delta_2)*mu_1 - delta_2*t))/(theta(u) + delta_2) - e**((theta(u) - delta_2)*mu_2)*omega_9(t))/(2*alpha_2*(theta(u) - delta_2))
        third_term = lambda_1(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_9(t)/(2*alpha_2)
        fourth_term = S(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(-delta_2*(t - mu_1))
    elif t>mu_2: # and t<T: simplified for numerical stability
        first_term = gamma_3*(p_3 + omega_1(u))*((1 - e**(delta_3*(mu_2 - t)))/delta_3 - e**(-delta_3*T)*omega_10(t))/(2*alpha_3*delta_3)
        second_term = gamma_3*omega_1(u)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**((theta(u) + delta_3)*mu_2 - delta_3*t))/(theta(u) + delta_3) - e**((theta(u) - delta_3)*T)*omega_10(t))/(2*alpha_3*(theta(u) - delta_3))
        third_term = 0
        fourth_term = S(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(-delta_3*(t - mu_2))
    return first_term + second_term + third_term + fourth_term

# Dependent variables - [Unverified]
def I_0(static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    t = mu_1
    second_term = -(a_1 - beta_1*p_1)*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u)
    third_term = -b_1*(t/theta(u) - (1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u)**2)
    fourth_term = gamma_1*S(0, static_variables)*omega_3(t, u)
    fifth_term_1 = lambda_1(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u)/(2*delta_1)
    fifth_term_2 = gamma_1*(p_1 + omega_1(u))/delta_1*(1/delta_1*((1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u) - omega_3(t, u)) - (e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u))/(2*delta_1))
    fifth_term_3 = gamma_1*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_1)*(1/(theta(u) + delta_1)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(-theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)) - omega_3(t, u)) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_1)*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u))/(2*delta_1))
    fifth_term = -gamma_1/(2*alpha_1)*(fifth_term_1 + fifth_term_2 + fifth_term_3)
    return (I_mu_1(static_variables) - second_term - third_term - fourth_term - fifth_term)/(e**(-theta(u)*t)) 

def I_mu_1(static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    t = mu_2
    second_term = -(D_0 - beta_2*p_2)*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_1)))/theta(u)
    third_term = -gamma_2*S(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(delta_2*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u)
    fourth_term_1 = gamma_2*(p_2 + omega_1(u))/delta_2*(1/delta_2*((1 - e**(theta(u)*(mu_1 - t)))/theta(u) - e**(delta_2*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u)) - (e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u))/(2*delta_2))
    fourth_term_2 = gamma_2*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_2)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(2*theta(u)*mu_1 - theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)*(theta(u) + delta_2)) - (e**((theta(u) + delta_2)*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u))/(theta(u) + delta_2) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_2)*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u))/(2*delta_2))
    fourth_term_3 = lambda_1(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u)/(2*delta_2)
    fourth_term = -gamma_2/(2*alpha_2)*(fourth_term_1 + fourth_term_2 + fourth_term_3)
    return (I_mu_2(static_variables) - second_term - third_term - fourth_term)/(e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_1)))

def I_mu_2(static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    t = T
    second_term = beta_3*p_3*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_2)))/theta(u)
    third_term = -a_2*(e**(-b_2*t) - e**((theta(u) - b_2)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) - b_2)
    fourth_term = -gamma_3*S(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(delta_3*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u)
    fifth_term_1 = gamma_3*(p_3 + omega_1(u))/delta_3*((1 - e**(theta(u)*(mu_2 - t)))/(theta(u)*delta_3) - (e**(delta_3*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u))/delta_3 - (e**(-delta_3*T)*omega_13(t, u))/(2*delta_3))
    fifth_term_2 = gamma_3*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_3)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(2*theta(u)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)*(theta(u) + delta_3)) - (e**((theta(u) + delta_3)*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u))/(theta(u) + delta_3) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_3)*T)*omega_13(t, u))/(2*delta_3))
    fifth_term_3 = lambda_1(T, static_variables)*e**(-delta_3*T)*omega_13(t, u)/(2*delta_3)
    fifth_term = -gamma_3/(2*alpha_3)*(fifth_term_1 + fifth_term_2 + fifth_term_3)
    return -(second_term + third_term + fourth_term + fifth_term)/(e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_2)))

# State variables - [Unverified]
def I(t, static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    if t>=0 and t<=mu_1:
        first_term = I_0(static_variables)*e**(-theta(u)*t)
        second_term = -(a_1 - beta_1*p_1)*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u)
        third_term = -b_1*(t/theta(u) - (1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u)**2)
        fourth_term = gamma_1*S(0, static_variables)*omega_3(t, u)
        fifth_term_1 = lambda_1(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u)/(2*delta_1)
        fifth_term_2 = gamma_1*(p_1 + omega_1(u))/delta_1*(1/delta_1*((1 - e**(-theta(u)*t))/theta(u) - omega_3(t, u)) - (e**(-delta_1*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u))/(2*delta_1))
        fifth_term_3 = gamma_1*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_1)*(1/(theta(u) + delta_1)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(-theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)) - omega_3(t, u)) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_1)*mu_1)*omega_11(t, u))/(2*delta_1))
        fifth_term = -gamma_1/(2*alpha_1)*(fifth_term_1 + fifth_term_2 + fifth_term_3)
    elif t>mu_1 and t<=mu_2:
        first_term = I_mu_1(static_variables)*e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_1))
        second_term = -(D_0 - beta_2*p_2)*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_1)))/theta(u)
        third_term = -gamma_2*S(mu_1, static_variables)*e**(delta_2*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u)
        fourth_term_1 = gamma_2*(p_2 + omega_1(u))/delta_2*(1/delta_2*((1 - e**(theta(u)*(mu_1 - t)))/theta(u) - e**(delta_2*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u)) - (e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u))/(2*delta_2))
        fourth_term_2 = gamma_2*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_2)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(2*theta(u)*mu_1 - theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)*(theta(u) + delta_2)) - (e**((theta(u) + delta_2)*mu_1)*omega_5(t, u))/(theta(u) + delta_2) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_2)*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u))/(2*delta_2))
        fourth_term_3 = lambda_1(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(-delta_2*mu_2)*omega_12(t, u)/(2*delta_2)
        fourth_term = -gamma_2/(2*alpha_2)*(fourth_term_1 + fourth_term_2 + fourth_term_3)
        fifth_term = 0
    elif t>mu_2: # and t<T: simplified for numerical stability
        first_term = I_mu_2(static_variables)*e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_2))
        second_term = beta_3*p_3*(1 - e**(-theta(u)*(t - mu_2)))/theta(u)
        third_term = -a_2*(e**(-b_2*t) - e**((theta(u) - b_2)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(theta(u) - b_2)
        fourth_term = -gamma_3*S(mu_2, static_variables)*e**(delta_3*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u)
        fifth_term_1 = gamma_3*(p_3 + omega_1(u))/delta_3*((1 - e**(theta(u)*(mu_2 - t)))/(theta(u)*delta_3) - (e**(delta_3*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u))/delta_3 - (e**(-delta_3*T)*omega_13(t, u))/(2*delta_3))
        fifth_term_2 = gamma_3*omega_1(u)/(theta(u) - delta_3)*((e**(theta(u)*t) - e**(2*theta(u)*mu_2 - theta(u)*t))/(2*theta(u)*(theta(u) + delta_3)) - (e**((theta(u) + delta_3)*mu_2)*omega_7(t, u))/(theta(u) + delta_3) - (e**((theta(u) - delta_3)*T)*omega_13(t, u))/(2*delta_3))
        fifth_term_3 = lambda_1(T, static_variables)*e**(-delta_3*T)*omega_13(t, u)/(2*delta_3)
        fifth_term = -gamma_3/(2*alpha_3)*(fifth_term_1 + fifth_term_2 + fifth_term_3)
    return first_term + second_term + third_term + fourth_term + fifth_term

# Object variable - [Unverified]
def Pi(static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    integrand_1 = lambda t: gamma_1*p_1*S(t, static_variables) - (h + theta(u)*c_d)*I(t, static_variables) - alpha_1*s_1(t, static_variables)**2/2
    integrand_2 = lambda t: gamma_2*p_2*S(t, static_variables) - (h + theta(u)*c_d)*I(t, static_variables) - alpha_2*s_2(t, static_variables)**2/2
    integrand_3 = lambda t: gamma_3*p_3*S(t, static_variables) - (h + theta(u)*c_d)*I(t, static_variables) - alpha_3*s_3(t, static_variables)**2/2
    integral_terms = quad(integrand_1, 0, mu_1)[0] + quad(integrand_2, mu_1, mu_2)[0] + quad(integrand_3, mu_2, T)[0]
    non_integral_terms = p_1*((a_1 - beta_1*p_1)*mu_1 + b_1*mu_1**2/2) + p_3*(a_2*(e**(-b_2*mu_2) - e**(-b_2*T))/b_2 - beta_3*p_3*(T - mu_2)) + p_2*(mu_2 - mu_1)*(D_0 - beta_2*p_2) - (K + c*I_0(static_variables) + u)
    return (non_integral_terms + integral_terms)/T

# Constraints - [Unverified]
def penalty(static_variables):
    p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T = static_variables
    constraints = []
    constraints.append(lambda: -(a_1 - beta_1*p_1 + gamma_1*S(0, static_variables)))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(D_0 - beta_2*p_2 + gamma_2*S(mu_1, static_variables)))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(a_2*e**(-b_2*mu_2) - beta_3*p_2 + gamma_3*S(mu_2, static_variables)))
    Gamma_1 = lambda: ((h + c_d*theta(u))*(e**(delta_3*mu_2)*(theta(u) - delta_3*(1 - e**(T*theta(u))))) - e**(delta_3*T)*(theta(u) - delta_3*(1 - e**(theta(u)*mu_2))))/((e**(delta_3*T) - e**(delta_3*mu_2))*theta(u)*(theta(u) - delta_3))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(p_1 - c))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(p_2 - c))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(p_3 - max(c, Gamma_1())))
    constraints.append(lambda: -(T - mu_2))
    psi = 10**6
    return sum([psi*max(0, constraint()) for constraint in constraints])

# Final objective function - [Unverified]
def F(static_variables):
    try:
        return -Pi(static_variables) + penalty(static_variables)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 10**6
# F = lambda static_variables: -Pi(static_variables) + penalty(static_variables)

"""## Validation"""

# Validation for s_i and S - [Verified]
import random

# Static variables
p_1 = 81.11
p_2 = 96.32
p_3 = 81.78
u = 87.21
T = 8.85
solution = [p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T]

validation_s_1 = lambda t: 70.8628 - 31.4823*e**(0.202554*t) + 14.2673*e**(0.25*t)
validation_s_2 = lambda t: 69.1923 - 15.3285*e**(0.202554*t) + 1.24483*e**(0.3*t)
validation_s_3 = lambda t: 44.6242 - 11.4964*e**(0.202554*t) + 1.71617*e**(0.3*t)
validation_S_1 = lambda t: 283.451 - 192.42*e**(-0.25*t) - 69.5652*e**(0.202554*t) + 28.5342*e**(0.25*t)
validation_S_2 = lambda t: 230.641 - 116.646*e**(-0.3*t) - 30.5011*e**(0.202554*t) + 2.07465*e**(0.3*t)
validation_S_3 = lambda t: 148.747 + 265.706*e**(-0.3*t) - 22.8758*e**(0.202554*t) + 2.86022*e**(0.3*t)

t = random.uniform(0, mu_1)
print(f'For t = {t}')
print(f's_1(t) diff: {validation_s_1(t) - s_1(t, solution)}')
print(f'S(t) diff:{validation_S_1(t) - S(t, solution)}\n')
t = random.uniform(mu_1, mu_2)
print(f'For t = {t}')
print(f's_2(t) diff: {validation_s_2(t) - s_2(t, solution)}')
print(f'S(t) diff:{validation_S_2(t) - S(t, solution)}\n')
t = random.uniform(mu_2, T)
print(f'For t = {t}')
print(f's_3(t) diff: {validation_s_3(t) - s_3(t, solution)}')
print(f'S(t) diff:{validation_S_3(t) - S(t, solution)}')

# Validation for I(0|mu_1|mu_2) and Pi - [Unverified]

# Static variables
p_1 = 81.11
p_2 = 96.32
p_3 = 81.78
u = 87.21
T = 8.85
solution = [p_1, p_2, p_3, u, T]

print('Expected I_0: 448.52')
print(f'Implemented I_0({solution}): {I_0(solution)}')
print(f'Implemented I_mu_1({solution}): {I_mu_1(solution)}')
print(f'Implemented I_mu_2({solution}): {I_mu_2(solution)}\n')

print('Expected Pi: 1348.82')
print(f'Implemented Pi({solution}): {Pi(solution)}')

"""# Solving the Optimization Problem

## Implemented PSO
"""

# https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2016-08-17/simple-particle-swarm-optimization-with-python/

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#
#   Originally by:
#       Nathan A. Rooy
#       Simple Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) with Python
#       July, 2016
#
#   Modified by:
#       Jinyoung, Sung
#       May, 2021
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

#--- IMPORT DEPENDENCIES ------------------------------------------------------+

import random
import math


#--- MAIN ---------------------------------------------------------------------+

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, x0):
        self.position_i = []          # particle position
        self.velocity_i = []          # particle velocity
        self.pos_best_i = []          # best position individual
        self.err_best_i = -1          # best error individual
        self.err_i = -1               # error individual

        for i in range(num_dimensions):
            self.velocity_i.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
            self.position_i.append(x0[i])

    # evaluate current fitness
    def evaluate(self, costFunc):
        self.err_i = costFunc(self.position_i)

        # check to see if the current position is an individual best
        if self.err_i<self.err_best_i or self.err_best_i==-1:
            self.pos_best_i = self.position_i
            self.err_best_i = self.err_i

    # update new particle velocity
    def update_velocity(self, pos_best_g):
        # ---------- Attention: Probably Needs Fine Tuning ---------- #
        w = 0.5       # constant inertia weight
        c1 = 1        # cognative constant
        c2 = 2        # social constant
        # ---------- Attention: Probably Needs Fine Tuning ---------- #

        for i in range(num_dimensions):
            r1 = random.random()
            r2 = random.random()

            vel_cognitive = c1*r1*(self.pos_best_i[i] - self.position_i[i])
            vel_social = c2*r2*(pos_best_g[i] - self.position_i[i])
            self.velocity_i[i] = w*self.velocity_i[i] + vel_cognitive + vel_social

    # update the particle position based off new velocity updates
    def update_position(self, bounds):
        for i in range(num_dimensions):
            self.position_i[i] = self.position_i[i] + self.velocity_i[i]

            # adjust maximum position if necessary
            if self.position_i[i] > bounds[i][1]:
                self.position_i[i] = bounds[i][1]

            # adjust minimum position if neseccary
            if self.position_i[i] < bounds[i][0]:
                self.position_i[i] = bounds[i][0]


class PSO:
    def __init__(self, costFunc, x0, bounds, num_particles, maxiter):
        global num_dimensions

        num_dimensions = len(x0)
        err_best_g = -1                   # best error for group
        pos_best_g = []                   # best position for group

        # establish the swarm
        swarm = []
        for i in range(num_particles):
            swarm.append(Particle(x0))

        # begin optimization loop
        for i in range(maxiter):
            print(i, err_best_g)
            # cycle through particles in swarm and evaluate fitness
            for j in range(num_particles):
                swarm[j].evaluate(costFunc)

                # determine if current particle is the best (globally)
                if swarm[j].err_i<err_best_g or err_best_g==-1:
                    pos_best_g = list(swarm[j].position_i)
                    err_best_g = float(swarm[j].err_i)

            # cycle through swarm and update velocities and position
            for j in range(num_particles):
                swarm[j].update_velocity(pos_best_g)
                swarm[j].update_position(bounds)

        # print final results
        print('FINAL')
        print(pos_best_g)
        print(err_best_g)

"""## Validation"""

# Definition of test optimization problems for validation

def func1(x):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        total+=x[i]**2
    return total

def func2(x):
    return x[0]**3

# Importing pre-built optimziers for validation
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing

# Running result of optimizers

#--- Choose optimization problem ----------------------------------------------+
"""
func = F
initials = [80, 90, 80, 40, 10]
bounds = [[c, 200], [c, 200], [c, 200], [50, 200], [mu_2, 20]]
"""

# """
func = func1
initials = [34, 30]
bounds = [[-200, 200], [-200, 200]]
# """

"""
func = func2
initials = [34]
bounds = [[-200, 200]]
"""


#--- Result printing ----------------------------------------------------------+
print(f'Choosen problem: {func}\n')

print('---------- Start of scipy.dual_annealing ----------')
print(dual_annealing(func, bounds))
print('---------- End of scipy.dual_annealing ----------\n')

print('---------- Start of myPSO ----------')
PSO(func, initials, bounds, num_particles=15, maxiter=30)
print('---------- End of myPSO ----------')
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem you're trying to solve in order for us to understand your solution and how to fix it.

Comment: Additionally, it seems far from being a minimal example. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok I will try to make some abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

As updated in the question description, I solved the problem by doing something like this.

```
# Through some naive test, I figured out
# 10**-323 is the closest value to zero in terms of powers of 10.
# That is, 10**-324 will actually pass the equality test == 0
epsilon = 10**-300

# Wrap any suspicious denominators with this function
def denominator(v):
    if v == 0:
        return epsilon
    else:
        return v

# For example
a = b / denominator(c)  # <-- a = b / c
```